# Loading most related entities of an object is very slow

Tags: entity-framework

[Continuing from my earlier question where I described my schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292066/extending-an-application-design-automatically-generating-data-items-from-templ) (repeated here for your convenience):

```
Parties ( PartyId, ClientId, AddressId, DateTime )
Tents ( PartyId, TentDetails... )
Clowns ( PartyId, AddressId, ClownDetails... )
SecurityAgentAssignment ( PartyId, AgentId, fromTime, untilTime )
Addresses ( AddressId, Street, City, State )
```

....and there's about 10 other tables of a similar design: all in a many-to-one relationship with `Parties`.

My ASP.NET MVC web application has a Summary page that displays every detail about a party. I'm using EF1.0 so I have to do my own eager-loading. Here's the logic I'm using:

```
Party dbParty = GetParty(partyId);

dbParty.Tents.EnsureLoaded();
dbParty.Clowns.EnsureLoaded();
foreach(Clown clown in dbParty.Clowns) clown.Address.EnsureLoaded();
dbParty.Security.EnsureLoaded();
foreach(SecurityAgentAssignment assignment in dbParty.Security) assignment.Agent.EnsureLoaded();
// and the 10 other relationships too
```

The code above takes about 3 seconds to run. Given this isn't eager-loading, but lazy-loading, surely it should just fire off about 15 simple SELECT queries and be done?

I don't have the SQL Server Profiler installed, and I don't know how to get the SQL generated when you're using `.Load` instead of `IQueryable`.

I use these extension methods as helpers:

```
private static readonly R.FieldInfo    _entityReferenceContext = typeof(RelatedEnd).GetField("_context", R.BindingFlags.Instance | R.BindingFlags.NonPublic );
private static readonly R.PropertyInfo _relatedEndOwner        = typeof(RelatedEnd).GetProperty("Owner", R.BindingFlags.Instance | R.BindingFlags.NonPublic );

private static Boolean IsAttached(this RelatedEnd relatedEnd) {

    Object context =  _entityReferenceContext.GetValue( relatedEnd );
    return context != null;
}

public static TEntity EnsureLoaded<TEntity>(this EntityReference<TEntity> eref) where TEntity : class, IEntityWithRelationships {

    // EntityReference<TEntity> derives from RelatedEnd.
    RelatedEnd erefAsRelatedEnd = (RelatedEnd)eref;

    erefAsRelatedEnd.EnsureLoaded();

    return eref.Value;
}

public static void EnsureLoaded(this RelatedEnd end) {

    IEntityWithRelationships owner       = (IEntityWithRelationships)_relatedEndOwner.GetValue( end, null );
    EntityObject             ownerEntity = owner as EntityObject;

    if( ownerEntity != null ) {

        if( ownerEntity.EntityState == EntityState.Added || ownerEntity.EntityState == EntityState.Detached ) return; // calling .Load on a Added object causes an exception.
    }

    if( end.IsAttached() && !end.IsLoaded ) end.Load();
}
```

Comment: Lazy loading is always slow. Every trip to the database is going to add a lot of time. Picture going to the store. If you were to need to get milk, steak, potatoes, and broccoli - it would make sense to get them all on the first trip instead of going from home to the store for each item. Each database trip is the same order of magnitude of difference for lazy loading as in the example of going to the grocery store. If you want to speed things up, eager load your values with `Include`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is moot - I was connecting to my database server over a VPN connection. I thought it would be okay as the ping time was only about 50ms between my computer and the database server, but I forget how chatty SQL Server is. Considering that it fires off about 60 queries at once it makes sense that `60 * 50ms == 3000ms`.

When I retried my application on the same LAN as the server (ping time < 1ms) the whole load operation executes in under 30ms with no need for any further optimization. Problem solved.